# How can I bind a parameter inside of ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

The best way to explain what I'm trying to do is to just show you an example. Here is the code I have:

```
<div ng-click="doSomething('path/to/script/with/{{parameter}}')">Click Here</div>
<div>Parameter is {{parameter}}</div> // I can see parameter here
```

The problem is that `{{parameter}}` is not binding to the `ng-click`. I can manually enter the parameter (e.g., '12') and the ng-click works fine, but I don't want to set it manually.

I have tried the following, but none of them work:

```
<div ng-click="doSomething('path/to/script/with/parameter')">Click Here</div>
<div ng-click="doSomething('path/to/script/with/'parameter)">Click Here</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have the parameter already in $scope of your controller, when the doSomething is called, why do you need it here?

Comment: agree with @Jaanus...but `doSomething('path/to/script/with/'+parameter)` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<div ng-click="doSomething('path/to/script/with/' + {{parameter}})">Click Here</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-click="doSomething('path/to/script/with/' + parameter)">Click Here</div>
```

or just read them from scope in your function.

Comment: @ChrisPaterson which one worked? Can't remember the correct syntax on top of my head.